# Unity OnBecameInvisible() fires though object is still visible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, visible, destroy

I have a Mesh Renderer and a script assigned to a rotating sphere with a hole in it. The sphere has no specific or special place in hierarchy, its just next to the camera. The script part looks like this:

```
void OnBecameInvisible() {
  Destroy(gameObject); 
}
```

Problem is, that when I pass the sphere with my ball, even though the sphere is still half visible, it gets deleted. I have no other camera in the scene, and the one Im using is marked as the main camera.

---

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq0xP.gif)

Comment: Hi an welcome to stack overflow. Questions about debugging need to include enough steps to reproduce the observed behavior. For unity questions, this means enough information about the scene, he hierarchy, and the components necessary. See [mre] and [ask] for more information

Comment: @Ruzhim I dont know which additional information I should include as I said everything that I can say and in my opinion is important.

Comment: Is the mesh renderer on the same object as the script?

Comment: @BenPeterson of course, yes

Comment: @Ruzhim no, im using the free version.

Comment: @Ruzihm whaaaat it doesn't in the free version? ^^ Always thought the Unity splash screen would be the only significant difference between free and pro ^^

Comment: @derHugo No, you're right. It was brought into free a while ago. Used to be pro only though :)

Comment: Well, [this is what I tried](https://pastebin.com/mjgGFyB1) in a completely fresh scene and attaching this to the camera (also not moving the scene camera). And `OnBecameInvisible` doesn't seem to be called when the sphere in the back gets occluded.

Comment: @Ruzihm hmm, ok. I added a video of it disappearing to my question, maybe you could have a look.

Comment: @Ruzihm I dont really know what you mean with frustum, english isnt my native language. But is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Let me rephrase, looks like that's happening because the center of the rotor is leaving the view of the camera. I can only guess that the bounds of the renderer on the same object the script is on only extends around the middle part of the rotor. Is that the case?

Comment: It actually was, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `OnBecameInvisible` for culling objects you've passed, just check if it's sufficiently behind the camera in `Update`:

```
Camera mainCam;
[SerializeField] float maxBehindDistance = 0.5f;

void Awake() { mainCam = Camera.main; }

void Update()
{
    Vector3 relPos = mainCam.transform.InverseTransformPoint(transform.position);
    if (relPos.z < -maxBehindDistance)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I already thought of this as an alternative solution, but Id really like to get behind the functionality of OnBecameInvisible()

Comment: it only culculate the object and camera position, while camera have fov and just negative z would not be a good solution. and I think anonym is asking how onbecamevisible works? and how it work if there is something infront and occlusion/